# playing background music and the user can stop or restart or pause the music

Tags: java, android, service, media-player

i am developing an Android game and i play some background music for our intro (we have an Intro Activity) but i want it to continue playing to the next Activity, and perhaps be able to stop or play the music again from anywhere within the application.

i have created Service class to do this

every thing is working fine but i only need is when the user stop the music the media player save getCurrentPosition(); so then i can play the music counted by seekTo(msec);

the main point is the music will not start from the beginning if the user stop the music in the middle of the length (it is like the user can pause the music and continue the music)

i use

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

to start the music

and i use

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

to stop the music

**this is my MyService class**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.game_music3);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }

    protected void onNewIntent() {
        player.pause();
    }
}
```

**if any thing is not clear to u please comment on my question and i will try to explain more 
thank you for ur help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try and save the current position of your music track on the [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?

Check the [Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) from the Android documentation.

Comment: i know how to save the current position and how to play it again but i coudnt do it in the Service class bez when the user play the music i call startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)); 
and  i dont have any idea about SharedPreferences
can u plz explain it 

and thx for ur help

Comment: @MohammedDwekat your answer is on the second link I gave you.